# a^17+b^17=c^17 with minimum relative error in python

Tags: python, math

How can we compute in python a,b,c  a^17+b^17=c^17 with the minimum relative error between a^17+b^17 and c^17 for a and b values beetween 100 and 10000?

```
amin,bmin=100,100
minerr=1.
for a in range(100,10001):
    for b in range(a+1,10001):
        c17=a**17+b**17
        sqc17=int(pow(c17,1./17.))
        err=float(abs(c17-sqc17**17))/float(sqc17)
        if err<minerr:
            minerr=err
            amin,bmin=a,b
print(amin,bmin,minerr)
```

My solution is bad because of low  precision of float
How could I improve this

Comment: I'm going to guess with Python code, and that's Python code you'll have to come up with yourself before asking a question here. Any attempt to solve the problem no matter how misguided or wrong is better than nothing.

Comment: It looks like you want us to write some code for you. While many users are willing to produce code for a coder in distress, they usually only help when the poster has already tried to solve the problem on his own. A good way to show this effort is to include the code you've written so far, example input (if there is any), the expected output, and the output you actually get (console output, tracebacks, etc.). The more detail you provide, the more answers you are likely to receive. Check the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: SO is not a code writing service, please attempt your own code first, and when you face issues with your code ask questions.

Comment: 1) You should have included that code when you first asked the question. 2) Your computation of `err` is off: the denominator should be either `sqc17**17` or `c17` (better). 3) You take the `int()` of the 17th root, but you should `round()`. 4) To find `sqc17`, the 17th root of `c17`, as an exact integer, you could store the 17th powers and use binary search to find the closest. With some work you could do an even faster search. If you don't like that storage you could use Newton-Raphson to calculate the 17th root iteratively. Search for `isqrt` (integer square root) for something similar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For `a<b` and `c=b+k` one gets

```
a^17 = (b+k)^17-b^17 = 17*k*b^16 + 8*17*k^2*b^15 + ...
```

which tells us that the valid choices for `a` are around `(17*k/b)^(1/17)*b` which reduces the choices for sensible `a` by a factor of 17. Thus changing the loop to

```
minerr = 1.0
amin = 100; bmin = 100;

for b in range(100, 1000+1):
    for c in range(b+1, 2*b):
        a = int(round( (c**17-b**17)**(1.0/17) )
        if a > b: break;
        relerr = abs( (1-(a**17+b**17)/float(c**17) )
        if relerr < minerr:
           print a,b,c,relerr
           amin=a; bmin=b; minerr=relerr
```

runs rather fast and has the output

```
 91 100 101 0.014295850232
 95 100 102 0.0127684524838
 91 101 102 0.0104995591939
 92 102 103 0.00622204374651
 93 103 104 0.00197150095955
 100 106 108 0.00195817126477
 107 108 112 0.00104974944998
 99 110 111 0.000393678252529
 139 158 159 3.78426050378e-05
 166 168 174 3.0425791517e-05
 186 190 196 1.5711666417e-05
 298 312 319 3.40065617555e-06
 318 323 334 1.40781743518e-06
 389 452 454 1.40251765757e-06
 543 628 631 6.18935889096e-07
 594 691 694 2.35972024587e-07
 815 993 995 5.41414728605e-08
```

Comment: with your code I have not the same output: <br>91 100 101 -0.014295850232 <br>
98 100 103 -0.0341677797797 <br>
102 102 106 -0.0399996810675

Comment: There was an absolute value in the executed code, copy-paste error. You could also additionally print `(a**17+b**17)**(1.0/17)` to see how close that is to `c`